# Applescript to assign an XML tag to all images in an InDesign document

Tags: xml, tags, applescript, adobe-indesign

I have a strange issue. My short applescript is kind of working. I want to tag  all the rectangles (these are what Adobe's library calls image frames) with the XML tag "Image".

```
set tagName to "Image"
set imageList to {}

tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2018"
tell active document

    set x to make XML element of first XML element with properties {markup tag:tagName}

    set imageList to every rectangle //there are 4 rectangles
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in imageList
        tell item i of imageList to markup using x

    end repeat

end tell

end tell
```

The log shows it is marking up each rectangle. But when I check the document, only the last rectangle in imageList actually shows that the XML tag is applied.

Moreover I can cancel or stop the script, and the last image before cancelling gets the tag. (That is, if I cancel when it is processing rectangle 2, rectangle 2 gets the image, but rectangles 1, 3, and 4 do not.

Comment: Tag the exact same images by hand. Can you tag more than one?

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of the applescript, which is to automate the process.

Comment: I get that. But I did not ask out of curiousness. Because if I'm right, you won't be able to.

Comment: Actually I was.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to a suggestion from Mark Anthony on MacScripter.net. It works for my needs. All the docs I'm processing have only images in them (no other graphics, frames, etc.)

```
set tagName to "Image"
set imageList to {}

tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2018"
tell active document

    set x to make XML element of first XML element with properties {markup tag:tagName}

    set imageList to every rectangle
    repeat with rect in imageList
        make XML element at XML element 1 with properties {markup tag:"Image", 
XML content:rect}
    end repeat

end tell

end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Your current criterion:

Firstly, the criterion that you're currently using to infer an *image* is prone to error. A page item whose *type* is `rectangle` does not necessarily equal an *image*. For instance; an image may be placed inside a circle, in which case its *type* will be an `oval` (not a `rectangle`).

The following line of code in your question which reads:

```
set imageList to every rectangle
```

will also include any page item(s) which were created using the *Rectangle Frame Tool* -  which in many `.indd` files will not be an image.

---

#### Recommended criterion:

To infer an image I recommend utilizing `all graphics` instead of `rectangles` to obtain a list images. InDesign's Applescript dictionary describes a `graphic` as:

> **`graphic`** An imported graphic in any graphic file format (including vector and bitmap formats.)

---

#### Solution:

The following AppleScript gist demonstrates a way to automate the process of tagging all images with an XML tag named *"Images"*. Each resultant tagged image will be added as a child XML element of the documents root XML element.

```
set tagName to "Image"

tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2018"
  tell active document
    if (count of page items) = 0 then return

    set locked of every layer to false
    set locked of every page item to false

    repeat with currentImage in all graphics
      if associated XML element of currentImage is not equal to nothing then
        untag associated XML element of currentImage
      end if
      make XML element at XML element 1 with properties {markup tag:tagName, XML content:currentImage}
    end repeat

  end tell
end tell
```

**Explanation**

1. `set tagName to "Image"` assigns the name of the XML element (i.e. "Image") to the `tagName` variable.
2. The line which reads:

   ```
   if (count of page items) = 0 then return
   ```

   ensures we exit the script early if the document contains no page items.
3. The lines which read:

   ```
   set locked of every layer to false
   set locked of every page item to false
   ```

   ensures all document layers and page items are unlocked. If an image was locked then it cannot be tagged.
4. The lines reading:

   ```
   if associated XML element of currentImage is not equal to nothing then
     untag associated XML element of currentImage
   end if
   ```

   *untags* any existing tag the image may have as it may be incorrect.
5. The line reading:

   ```
   make XML element at XML element 1 with properties {markup tag:tagName, XML content:currentImage}
   ```

   carries out the actual tagging of the image.

Comment: Thank you. The Indesign documents I'm working with have only images, so every rectangle is an image. I use InDesign to size and position thumbnails, hero images, slider images, etc, then output to HTML with the fixed size. But now we are changing the design of the website, so I need to export the documents as XML, which creates a folder and based on my selection will export the original image. So yes, I know a rectangle isn't necessarily an image, but in my case it will be.